# Apache storm supervisor stops automatically

Tags: java, apache, bigdata, apache-zookeeper, apache-storm

I have used two systems to configure apache strom cluster.

system1:

- Zookeeper server
- Nimbus
- UI

System2:

- Zookeeper client
- Storm supervisor

When I start storm supervisor by, ***.\storm supervisor*** in power shell command line, it started, but after few seconds it automatically stopped.

Is anyone faced same issue when setting storm cluster in multiple system ?

Am I missing any configuration ? or Any command line argument should I pass when starting storm supervisor ?

How to resolve this issue ?

Following is the latest config I have used.

### storm.yaml nimbus config

storm.zookeeper.servers:
 - "localhost"

storm.local.dir: "G:\software\apache-storm\apache-storm-1.1.2\datadir"

nimbus.host: "localhost"

### Storm.yaml supervisor config:

storm.zookeeper.servers:
 - "192.168.1.10"

storm.local.dir: "F:\software\apache-storm-1.1.2\datadir"

nimbus.host : "192.168.1.10"

supervisor.slots.ports:
- 6700
- 6701
- 6702
- 6703

### Zookeeper server config:

tickTime=2000

initLimit=10

syncLimit=5

dataDir=G:\software\zookeeper\zookeeper-3.4.6\data

clientPort=2181

maxClientCnxns=60

server.1=192.168.1.10:2888:3888

### Zookeeper client config

tickTime=2000

initLimit=10

syncLimit=5

dataDir=F:\software\zookeeper-3.4.6\data

clientPort=2181

server.1=192.168.1.10:2181

cnxTimeout=60

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should go check your supervisor log in storm-home/logs/supervisor.log, it'll likely tell you what's wrong.

Since you're on Windows, I'd bet that you're not running the supervisor as administrator. Try doing that, and see if that solves it.

Comment: Rohde Dossing - Thank you sir. It working fine now. I just started the supervisor as admin, now its working